# Delayed prop update when using React Hooks and Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a React class component where the view depends on a global state called `props.filtered_table_data` stored in Redux Store.

I use `useReducer` to apply filters to the state

```
const init_filter = { OWNER: '', TEAM: '' }

    const [filter, dispatch] = useReducer((state, action) => {
        switch (action.type) {
            case 'OWNER':
                return { ...state, OWNER: action.option }
            case 'TEAM':
                return { ...state, TEAM: action.option }
            case 'RESET':
                return init_filter
            default:
                return state
        }
    }, init_filter)
```

These filters get applied when I select through a dropdown.

```
<Select
    className="select-filter"
    type="owner"
    onItemSelect={(optionItem) => { handleFilter('OWNER', optionItem); ; filterData()}}
>   
</Select>
```

And `filterData()` is the function that handles the filtering of the data. It creates a new array, filters the data based on the filter and updates it at the end by doing

`props.filterTable(newArray)`

`filterTable` is just a redux action that updates the `props.filtered_table_data`.

The filtering works well, but there is a delay in the update.
When I select a new filter, the previous filter gets applied to the data.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Try creating a [mcve]. If you can reproduce this on codesandbox, this would be wildly more useful to debug.

Comment: If the previous filter is being applied, it means your component isn't re-rendering. Assuming the user can view all the data, I'd suggest changing the way you filter by doing the filtering on the actual component and only use the Redux store to update the current filter.